# virtualbox 6.1 startup error: “vboxadd-service … failed!”

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

Using VBox 6.1.12 on Win10 Pro and Ubuntu 18.04
Getting startup error: **vboxadd-service.service failed**.  So the network does not work at all - cant even ping, no apt-get.

The machine/VBox used to work fine till I recently enabled hyper-V on my win10 host, which likely may have been the cause of this - but now I disabled hyper-V. But I still get error and cant use the VM - no network.

However, VMWare workstation (that also had stopped working) - started working after disabling hyper-V

Comment: How did you disable Hyper-V. Please list all of the steps you performed.

Comment: https://petri.com/how-to-disable-hyper-v-completely-in-windows-10